# Django NoReverseMatch u'"proto' is not a registered namespace

Tags: python, django

- Django 1.6.1
- Python 2.7.5
- ISP webfaction

After upgrading to django 1.6.1, I get the following error on the root `/`.

```
NoReverseMatch at /proto/
u'"proto' is not a registered namespace
```

My urls.py is (truncated):

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
   'views',
...
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^proto/', include('proto.urls',namespace="proto",app_name='proto'),),
    url(r'^login/$',
        auth_views.login,
        {'template_name': 'login.html'},
        name='auth_login'),
...
)
```

From my webserver instance, I can start up a python shell and do a reverse lookup.

```
$ django-admin.py shell
django-admin.py shell
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 16 2013, 20:16:09)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
>>> reverse("proto:index")
'/proto/'
```

Moreover, my webserver displays the admin pages fine.

If I comment out the `{% url "proto:index" %}` in `base.html`, I get the following error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /proto/
Reverse for '"auth_logout"' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

The code works fine on the localhost (i.e., `django-admin.py runserver`).

Summary,

- (a) works on localhost,
- (b) admin urls are resolved,
- (c) namespace is not resolved, and
- (d) other urls are not resolved.

Comment: It looks like you might have a typo somewhere with '"proto'. Admin site works because the url is found before the proto namespace is loaded. Can you include `proto.urls`? Have you added it to installed_apps?

Comment: Actually, the typo is probably somewhere in one of your templates. Look (or grep) for something like '"proto:index'. I'd check your index and/or base templates first.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is no typo; it works locally and moving the lines around does not change the solution.

Comment: I moved the original version of django to django.1.4.2 and put 1.6.1 in django. Per suggestion by webfaction tech I removed the old django completely and this problem went away. But, alas, there is a different problem. Again, thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: The more I think about it, typo doesn't make much sense. Reverse works in the shell but not in apache2. There are at least two differences: python vs modpython and the environment variables. There appears to be something about running in modpython that is different.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you're using reverse('...') as the parameter to a CBV? If so, you'll need to use reverse_lazy.

Read about this in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy

Even if this doesn't apply to you, this will likely help other who arrive here (this question ranks first in google at the moment for 'django not a registered namespace').